# Opacity in css for individual tags

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css to make all items in the main `DIV` of my page to be transparented:

```
#wrapper
{
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); 
   -moz-opacity: 0.9; 
   opacity: 0.9; 
}
```

This works and everything gets transparented. But for example I DO NOT want the texts, images and buttons to be transparented. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
#wrapper{
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

You will have to use `rgba()` to achieve this. Take a look at this website:

- http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/

I did also come over this problematic and solving it with rgba() is really the best way to get around this. Using transparent images as background, in my opinion is not as flexible as it should be and I'm really against using images when you can achieve the effects you want in other simpler ways.

Comment: The only browser who doesn't support that is the elder versions of IE9- and the Opera 9.- version. But there are many workarounds for IE9- and also Opera 9.-

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a transparent background (in png) for your wrapper and do not use opacity

Comment: Is there any reason for the negative vote ? Can anyone explain ? I think my solution is a valid one.

Comment: I can only assume the -1 is because pngs are bascially a last-resort for backgrounds, and they can't affect text opacity, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The child-elements inherit the opacity and you can not directly change it back. But there is a workaround http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/